# Problems with bool on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_course/Questao.dart';
import 'package:flutter_course/Resposta.dart';

class Questionario extends StatelessWidget {
  final perguntas;
  final perguntaSelecionada;
  final responder;

  Questionario({
    @required this.perguntaSelecionada,
    @required this.perguntas,
    @required this.responder,
  })

 
  bool get temPerguntaSelecionada {
    return perguntaSelecionada < perguntas.length;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var respostas = temPerguntaSelecionada
        ? perguntas[perguntaSelecionada]["responder"]
        : null;

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Questao(perguntas[perguntaSelecionada]["texto"]),
        ...respostas.map((t) => Resposta(t, responder)).tolist()
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Guys, i'm having problems with variable `bool`, it's showing a red line saying that a function body must be provided.
They're saying for me to try to add a function body, and i don't know how to add a function body inside of a class, can you guys help me please?

Comment: Which line is the error reported against?

Comment: @jamesdlin,  bool get temPerguntaSelecionada

Comment: Start firstly by defining the type of variables that your class uses, con `final` those variables are `dynamic`, `length` function works with certain classes only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a semicolon(;) at the end of your constructor.

```
Questionario({
    @required this.perguntaSelecionada,
    @required this.perguntas,
    @required this.responder,
  })
```

should be

```
Questionario({
    @required this.perguntaSelecionada,
    @required this.perguntas,
    @required this.responder,
  });
```